# Memory leak in delete loop

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, delete-operator

"You have some memory leaks in the end due to a logical error in your deletion loop."

My friend said this and I don't see it.

```
for(int i=0; i<nrOfAvailableSeats; i++)
{
    delete passengers[i];
}
delete [] passengers;
```

Comment: We need more code.

Comment: what is the size of `passengers` array? what is the value of `nrOfAvailableSeats`? we are not telepathic.

Comment: Key question(s): how many `passengers` were created, how big is the `passengers` array?

Comment: Here is the whole .cpp file in question: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3140142/FlightHandler.cpp

Comment: @Andres - " int nrOfAvailableSeats=100; " means nothing.

Comment: We don't want "the whole .cpp file in question". We want a complete, _minimal_ testcase.

Answer (score 4):

You start with `nrOfAvailableSeats` set to initial value (100), then over the program runtime it might decrement (since you have

```
nrOfAvailableSeats--;
```

in your code) and so when you use it in your loop you won't `delete` some of the objects.

At the very least you have to define a global constant:

```
const int PlaneCapacity = 100;
```

and use it to initialize `nrOfAvailableSeats` and in both the array creation and deletion loops.

Comment: I have added const int MaxAvailableSeats=100; and nrOfAvailableSeats=MaxAvailableSeats; in line 15 and 16 and changed line 50 to MaxAvailableSeats. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3140142/FlightHandlerNEW.cpp

Comment: @Anders Andersson: Great, now that problem must be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you delete array of passengers after deleting **only some** of its elements. 
So when you do `delete [] passengers;` some ( [i], [i+1], ... ) elements may stay undeleted.

Comment: only if the lenght of passengers array is not the same as nrOfAvailableSeats.

Comment: How do you know?  We don't even know the size or type of the array.

Comment: Well it _looks_ like a variable, not a constant and since he does not use sizeof pirouette it was safe to assume the worst, he did not provide full source at the moment of answer.

Answer (score 0):

In linked file there is code: `nrOfAvailableSeats--;`

And when you free your data you mignt have memleak because `nrOfAvailableSeats` can be < 100

Comment: How can I fix the memory leak? I'm fairly new to C++ and programming in general.

Comment: Use constant, something like: `const int MaxAvailableSeats=100;` and then assign `nrOfAvailableSeats=MaxAvailableSeats`, then when you finished, loop by `MaxAvailableSeats`

Comment: I have changed line 15, 16 and 50. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3140142/FlightHandlerNEW.cpp

Comment: Should this fix the memory leak now?

Answer (score 0):

You initialized all available seats to 0/null,thus, in the cleanup phase, just iterate over all the 100 elements and delete each item.
(Edit: checking for null pointer prior to delete is redundant, nevermind that.)

Alternatively use a std::vector if you are allowed to use the STL. 
Then just iterate through the vector and delete them all, since you will only have so much items in the vector as you actually use them. (If you only work with push and pop).

To delete something from a vector that is in use (not about to be completely emptied),  is to swap the item you want to delete with `vector.back()`, then delete `vector.back()` and then `pop_back()`.
Note: this invalidates any iterators, you'll have to re-assign them properly, or in the case of only one item you wished to delete, just break out of the iteration loop, via `break` or `return`.

```
#include "Passenger.h"
#include "EconomyClass.h"
#include "FirstClass.h"
#include <vector>



int main()
{
std::vector<Passenger*> passengers

//add passengers the vector grows when needed, it does so by copying the items, which, in the 
//case of raw pointers like this, fast.
passengers.push_back(new FirstClass(name, purpose, chair));
passengers.push_back(new EconomyClass(name, purpose, food));

//delete all, starting from the back of the stack
//check the std::vector reference online for details
std::vector<Passenger*>::reverse_iterator start,end;
start = passengers.rbegin();
end = passengers.rend();

//iterate through all items, in this case, 2
for(;start!=end;++start)
{
delete *start;
}
//optional since it would get called on cleanup anyway)
passengers.clear();

}
```

Comment: As I said before I'm new to C++ and we haven't yet done this sort of programming which you've posted above.

Comment: @Anders Andersson Ah, alright, I see, well yeah I'd go with stepping over all 100 items and checking for pointer validity, just to be sure, then, but I'm aware that that isn't really a good answer to WHY memory leaks in the original problem.

Comment: I think the memory leak is fixed now in my new file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3140142/FlightHandlerNEW.cpp

Comment: @Anders Andersson, indeed, since it's doing just that, iterate over all 100 and delete them all, It doesn't check for null pointers, though, but now that I see that, I think deleting a null pointer does nothing bad, so I guess a check would have been redundant after all. Edit: yes, it is redundant.